# Oracle- calculating difference between two time when value of another fields is changed

Tags: oracle

I need to calculation time when another field change in oracle. 
For instance, I have table which has 3 fields. Username, Date, and Status, all of them are varchar. Status has two values 0,1. Now, if for one user changing status happen i need to calculate time beteween them. in fact i want to calculate between when status='0' to become 1. For example, user a in 20170101 has status=0 until 20170105, the difference date between them is 3, also from 20170107 has status='0' again until 20170110, the difference is 2. so 2+3=5

username    status  date
a   0   20170101
a   1   20170105
a   0   20170107
a   1   20170110

username    status  day
a   0   5

Comment: 1. Why is "date" in VARCHAR data type and not in DATE data type? You can subtract dates and get the answer immediately; you can't (generally) subtract strings. 1. Why is the difference between 0101 and 0105 equal to 3 and not 4? You need to explain the logic further, since this does not agree with kindergarten arithmetic.

Comment: my table is created and i have just access to it and when this column is created use varchar. my point is when the value of another field is change how i can calculate the time, i want to calculation every user how many day has status zero

Comment: Are the following situations possible, and if so how should they be handled? (1) For a user, the most recent row has status = 0, which means that user is *currently* in that status. Do you need to compute anything for that (perhaps from the "date" to the current date?) (2) You have a user with several consecutive rows with status = 0, and then a row with status = 1. Do you use the FIRST row with status = 0 for the computation, or only the most recent row with status = 0? Using the FIRST row with status = 0 would make more sense in this case - if such a situation is even possible in your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be looking for something like this. However, there are many assumptions here - see my Comments under your original post. In the solution below, I kept the "-1" from your weird date arithmetic. I also ignore status 0 if it is not followed by status 1. And if consecutive rows with the same status are possible, I only take CONSECUTIVE rows with status changing from 0 to 1. This may not be the correct handling if such situations are possible.

```
with
  inputs ( username, status, dt ) as (
    select 'a', '0', '20170101' from dual union all
    select 'a', '1', '20170105' from dual union all
    select 'a', '0', '20170107' from dual union all
    select 'a', '1', '20170110' from dual
  )
-- End of SIMULATED inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE. Use your actual table and column names.
select username,
       sum(diff) as days_in_status_0
from   (
  select username,
         case when status = '1' 
               and lag(status) over (partition by username order by dt) = '0'
              then to_date(dt, 'yyyymmdd') - 
                   to_date(lag(dt) over(partition by username order by dt), 'yyyymmdd')
                   - 1
         end  as diff
  from   inputs
)
group by username
;

USERNAME  DAYS_IN_STATUS_0
--------  ----------------
a                        5
```